# RedisGraph - Combining multiple directives with MERGE

Tags: cypher, anormcypher, redisgraph

I am currently running the below query on Neo4J

```
match (p:Initial{state: 'Initial', name: 'Initial'}), (c:Encounter{code:'abcd', state: 'Encounter', name: 'Encounter1'})
merge (p)-[:raw {person_id:'1234', type:'Encounter', code:'abcd'}]->(c)
```

However I am unable to do the same query on RedisGraph. 
According to what I have found so far, Redis does not seem to support [combining `MERGE`with other directives](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisgraph/cypher_support/#readingwriting-clauses)

1. Is there any workaround to this?
2. Can the query be changed to allow it to execute the same functionality without the match statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only option I see right now is to split this into two queries,
The first one checks to see if p is connected to c:

```
MATCH (p:Initial{state: 'Initial', name: 'Initial'})-[:raw {person_id:'1234', type:'Encounter', code:'abcd'}]->(c:Encounter{code:'abcd', state: 'Encounter', name: 'Encounter1'}) RETURN p,c
```

If the above query returns empty issue a second query to form the relation:

```
MATCH (p:Initial{state: 'Initial', name: 'Initial'})(c:Encounter{code:'abcd', state: 'Encounter', name: 'Encounter1'}) CREATE (p)-[:raw {person_id:'1234', type:'Encounter', code:'abcd'}]->(c)
```